# Which is the Dockerfile encoding?

Tags: encoding, docker

Defining my `Dockerfile` I got to this line:

```
...
MAINTAINER Ramón <ramon@example.com>
...
```

Which encoding shall I use to save this file?

Shall I escape non ASCII characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering [Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/) is done in [Go](http://golang.org/), and [Go has native support for utf-8](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/), it is best to save a Dockerfile directly encoded in UTF-8.

That way, *all* characters (ASCII or not) are supported.

See "[Dealing with encodings in Go](http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2012/04/dealing_with_encodings_in_go/)".

> Even though Go has good support for UTF-8 (and minimal support for UTF-16), it has no built-in support for any other encoding.
>   If you have to use other encodings (e.g. when dealing with user input), you have to use third party packages, like for example [go-charset](http://code.google.com/p/go-charset/).

Here, it is best if the Dockerfile is directly encoded in UTF-8.

---

Update July 2016, docker 1.12-rc5 adds:

- [PR 23372](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23372): Support unicode characters in parseWords
- [PR 23234](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23234): Skip UTF-8 BOM bytes from Dockerfile and .dockerignore if exist

Comment: UTF-8 is the safest bet on almost all systems these days, except Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the locale correctly, remove the accent, check the encoding with a basic `docker run -it container env` and then put a correct encoding, the "Bible" on that is http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/

Comment: I don't think this is about the locale used in a running container (as explained in https://oncletom.io/2015/docker-encoding/), and more about the encoding used in a Dockerfile in order to support non-ASCII character in said Dockerfie.